# Why is this not causing an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, infinite-loop

From Eloquent JavaScript. Since "i" starts at -1 and decrements by 1 in each loop, this should never reach the end condition "i >= 0". Yet the code works.

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([]));
//null
```

Comment: The loop runs while `i >= 0`. Is `-1 >= 0`?

Comment: array.length would return 0, so i would be -1. The while loop then checks is i (-1) greater than or equal to zero, which it is not, so it exits and returns null.

Comment: @ScottMarcus what if the array is empty?  The length is zero, correct?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yeah there is, see how they're calling the function -- with an empty array.

Comment: @AndrewLi My bad. Didn't see that.

Answer (score 14):

Your analysis is wrong.  If `array` is empty, `i` starts as -1, this fails the condition `i >= 0`, so the loop never executes.  The condition must be fulfilled for the loop to *continue*, not for the loop to exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) // i = -1, i is not greater than or equal 0 so it never enters the loop
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  // list is null and loop finished with i -1
  return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([]));
//null
```

So basically following would be the statements running:

1. arrayToList([]);
2. var list = null;
3. var i = array.length - 1 // -1
4. check for i >= 0 which is false
5. return list;
6. console.log(null)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
    code block to be executed
}
```

Statement 1 is executed before the loop (the code block) starts.

Statement 2 defines the condition for running the loop (the code block).

Statement 3 is executed each time after the loop (the code block) has been executed.

**Statement 2 is false so loop body is not entered**